# iOS: icons are visible in app despite they're not existing physically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Well, I had a folder with icons, and yesterday I deleted it and cleaned the app. However, these icons never disappeared from my app.

- Checked if the images somewhere else. No, deleted from my Mac.
- Did reset iPhone simulator.
- Have deleted this app from device.

Can somebody shed the light on this issue?

EDIT: May 1, 2012

Today, after reseting and cleaning the project again I've got rid of icons in simulator. Again, I've deleted my app from device and run it again. I've got damn icons.
Why in device it doesn't looks similar as in simulator.

Comment: Do Product -> Clean. Sometimes images like that are cached and show up even though they were deleted.

Comment: "Yesterday I've deleted it and cleaned app up..."

Comment: Just some English language advice "cleaned the app" and "cleaned the app up" have two different meanings.  That's probably why he told you to do Product->Clean.

Comment: Oops. Checked my text. Ye, just cleaned app. Typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to reset your iphone Simulator and clean the project. or u should check,that on click of there is two option come,first only references and second move to trash,which option have you clicked?

Comment: Hello. Moved to trash. The icons are not in bundle anymore.